# Using XPath in strings

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

Let's say we have the following response from a browser:

```
<div>
  <tr id="1"></tr>
  <tr id="2">
  <!--
    <div class="A">AAA</div>
    <div class="C">BBB</div>
    <div class="C">CCC</div>
  -->
  </tr>
</div>
```

Getting the comment string using xpath in scrapy should be something like:

`response.xpath(//tr[@id="2"]/comment())`

So my question - is there any easy way to extract the values of `<div class="C"`> tags inside the comment?
One way would be remove the comment tags in the string `<!-- (...) -->`, and use `lxml.html`library to transform the result into an HTML again and use xpath in it, but I'm pretty sure it should be an easier way...

I'd appreciate any help. Cheers!

Comment: Parsing the content of the comment with `lxml.html` is a good solution in my opinion.

Comment: _but I'm pretty sure it should be an easier way..._ What did you have in mind, that would be easier?

Comment: I expressed myself very badly, it was only a guess. Anyway, I was thinking in a native function of Xpath or something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parsing the content of the comment with `lxml.html` is a good solution in my opinion.

**Python Code**

```
from lxml import etree
from io import StringIO

parser = etree.HTMLParser()

html_text = """<div>
  <tr id="1"></tr>
  <tr id="2">
  <!--
    <div class="A">AAA</div>
    <div class="C">BBB</div>
    <div class="C">CCC</div>
  -->
  </tr>
</div>"""

tree = etree.parse(StringIO(html_text), parser)

comment = tree.xpath("//tr[@id='2']/comment()")

comment_text = str(comment[0])

# string needs an outermost element in order to be parseable

comment_text = comment_text.replace("<!--", "<html>").replace("-->", "</html>")

embedded_tree = etree.parse(StringIO(comment_text), parser)

embedded_tree.xpath("//div[@class='C']/text()")
```

**Output**

```
['BBB', 'CCC']
```

Comment: Thanks Mathias! It's been very useful

Answer (score 1):

Although there is an answer, I would like to recommend another solution, because it is really simple and suitable for extracting data from XML.

```
from simplified_scrapy.simplified_doc import SimplifiedDoc
html = '''
<div>
  <tr id="1"></tr>
  <tr id="2">
  <!--
    <div class="A">AAA</div>
    <div class="C">BBB</div>
    <div class="C">CCC</div>
  -->
  </tr>
</div>
'''
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
divs = doc.select('#2').selects('.C')
print ([div.text for div in divs])
```

Result:

```
['BBB', 'CCC']
```

Here are more examples of SimplifiedDoc [here](https://github.com/yiyedata/simplified-scrapy-demo/tree/master/doc_examples)

Comment: We can get the same result with print (doc.selects('#2>.C>text()'))

Answer (score 0):

One liner solution with XPath 2.0 (regex can be of course optimized) :

```
normalize-space(replace(normalize-space(//comment()),'(.div class="[^C]">.{3})|(.div class="C">)|(<.div>)',''))
```

Output :

```
'BBB CCC'
```